# How can I change the stack order of jquery dialogs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling with the problem of getting the dialog boxes on top of the others. If I click on the first one and then on the second one, the second one remains on top of the first one, even if I click on the link for the first one again. Can you help me? I need the first one to come back to top as someone clicks on the button again.

Thanks in advance! :)

```js
(function() {  
    var dialog = document.getElementById('bildergalerie-window');  
    document.getElementById('bildergalerie').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.show();  
    };  
    document.getElementById('bildergalerie-exit').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.close();  
    };  
})();

(function() {  
    var dialog = document.getElementById('ansprechpartner-window');  
    document.getElementById('ansprechpartner').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.show();  
    };  
    document.getElementById('ansprechpartner-exit').onclick = function() {  
        dialog.close();  
    };  
})();
```

```html
<a href="#" id="bildergalerie">First Button</a>
  <a href="#" id="ansprechpartner">Second Button</a>



<dialog id="bildergalerie-window">
    <iframe src="#">aaa</iframe>
    <button id="bildergalerie-exit">close A. </button> 
</dialog>

   
    <dialog id="ansprechpartner-window">  
    <iframe src="#">bbb</iframe>
    <button id="ansprechpartner-exit">close B. </button> 
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small "addition" to your code...
Playing with z-indexes an position absolute.

It works.

```js
(function() { 
  var dialog = document.getElementById('bildergalerie-window');  
  document.getElementById('bildergalerie').onclick = function() {  
   dialog.show();
   if($("#ansprechpartner-window").css("display")!="none"){
    console.log("If b opened...");
    $("#bildergalerie-window").css({"position":"absolute","z-index":2});
    $("#ansprechpartner-window").css({"position":"absolute","z-index":1});
   }
  };  
  document.getElementById('bildergalerie-exit').onclick = function() {  
   dialog.close();  
  };  
 })();

 (function() {  
  var dialog = document.getElementById('ansprechpartner-window');  
  document.getElementById('ansprechpartner').onclick = function() {  
   dialog.show();
   if($("#bildergalerie-window").css("display")!="none"){
    console.log("If a opened...");
    $("#ansprechpartner-window").css({"position":"absolute","z-index":2});
    $("#bildergalerie-window").css({"position":"absolute","z-index":1});
   }
  };  
  document.getElementById('ansprechpartner-exit').onclick = function() {  
   dialog.close();  
  };  
 })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="bildergalerie">First Button</a>
   <a href="#" id="ansprechpartner">Second Button</a>



 <dialog id="bildergalerie-window">
  <iframe src="#">aaa</iframe>
  <button id="bildergalerie-exit">close A. </button> 
 </dialog>

    
 <dialog id="ansprechpartner-window">  
  <iframe src="#">bbb</iframe>
  <button id="ansprechpartner-exit">close B. </button> 
 </dialog>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! :)
I will try it with about 5 dialogs now!

Comment: Great. Have fun! ;)